# DNS Lookups in Java using JNDI and Default Domain

Tags: java, dns, jndi

I am using JNDI in Java to perform DNS lookups in my application to resolve A records - running under Java 8 on Windows 7. However, I am having trouble resolving records unless I specify the complete host entry including domain name.

Java appears to be ignoring the DNS search list which is configured on the PC. I don't have a problem including the domain name, if that is what Java requires, but I can't find a public method to obtain the domains in the search list.

The following SSCCE uses the private method `sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration` to obtain the DNS search list, but I shouldn't use it as it is an internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

public class SSCCE {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] hostsToLookup = new String[] { "testhost", "testhost.mydomain.com" };

    try {
      System.out.println("DNS Search List:");
      for (Object o: sun.net.dns.ResolverConfiguration.open().searchlist()) {
        System.out.println(" " + o);
      }

      Properties p = new Properties();
      p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
      InitialDirContext idc = new InitialDirContext(p);

      for (String h : hostsToLookup) {
        System.out.println("Host: " + h);
        try {
          Attributes attrs = idc.getAttributes(h, new String[] { "A" });
          Attribute attr = attrs.get("A");

          if (attr != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attr.size(); i++) {
              System.out.println(" " + attr.get(i));
            }
          }
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println(" undefined");
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this using just the host part it doesn't resolve, but when I manually add the domain from the search list then it does:

```
DNS Search List:
 mydomain.com
Host: testhost
 undefined
Host: testhost.mydomain.com
 192.0.2.1
```

Is it possible to either make Java honour the DNS search list using JNDI or is there a public method to obtain the DNS search list?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. What did you end up doing?

Comment: With the introduction of Java 9, the above private method is no longer accessible and I haven't been able to find a public alternative method. I ended up providing a `JTextField` where the user can manually enter the search domains.

Comment: Ouch... I was hoping that Java 9's promise to make public APIs for all the private stuff would lead somewhere, but it seems like it's closing more doors than it's opening. :(